# Restart Wacom Driver

Tags: driver

I found numerous references to shutting down and restarting Wacom driver.
That path to the driver is listed as

```
/Library/Application Support/Tablet/WacomTabletDriver/Contents/MacOS/WacomTabletDriver
```

This file does not exist in Catalina at least.

So how does one restart service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various paths are given in this post on Reddit. It seems to heavily depend on what version of the driver you're using as Wacom apparently change it regularly.

> - /Applications/Wacom Tablet/.Tablet/WacomTabletDriver.app
> - /Applications/Wacom Tablet/.Tablet/WacomTouchDriver.app
> - /Library/Application Support/Tablet/TabletDriver.app
> - /Library/Application Support/Tablet/WacomTabletDriver.app
> - /Library/Application Support/Tablet/WacomTouchDriver.app

https://www.reddit.com/r/wacom/comments/kk9405/comment/gh17wa8/

Note that in your path, you have said …/Contents, which implies the contents of a package, but the previous path component does not end with a package extension like `.app`. If you're pasting the path in somewhere, try instead looking at this path through Finder and looking in each folder for similar named items for each component of the path.

You don't need the path to a process to find the process if it is running nor to kill it. Search Activity Monitor (when filtered for All Processes not My Processes) for terms like ‘wacom’, ‘tablet’ and ‘driver’. Sample the process to get the path to it and kill it for the launch agent to restart it.

If the process is controlled by a launch agent or daemon, search `launchctl list` for the terms above and [`launchctl unload`/`launchctl load`](https://serverfault.com/a/194886/181405) it.

Comment: I also used sample process in Activity Monitor to get additional information. I quit process in Activity Monitor, and double-clicked/Applications/Wacom Tablet/.Tablet/WacomTabletDriver.app. After screen-saver is activated or wake from sleep, Wacom loses all information. Restarting service much more convenient than restarting mac.